# jupyter or pandas rounds Time data and continues working with the round data

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

So i want to resample data from accelerometers to 100Hz.
Now i face the problem that everything is going alright until the 100 second. From this moment on it changes the frequency without my permission. The problem is it then keeps on working with these rounded numbers and therefore my desired frequency is changed to 1 seconds instead of 0.01.
I tried all different stuff like set display options or round the numbers myself.
As the pictures show the original data is clearly not the problem.

```
acc["Time_s"]=0
acc.Time_s=pd.to_datetime(acc.Time, unit="s")
acc['time_str'] = acc['Time_s'].dt.strftime('%S.%f')
acc.set_index('Time_s', inplace=True)

acc_down=acc.resample("0.01S").mean()
acc_loc=acc_down.loc[acc_down["Time"]>=99.0]

(acc_loc.head(20))
```

[image]

[image]